# Full featured language plugins for Eclipse Orion

Tags: eclipse, amazon-ec2, eclipse-che, eclipse-orion

I read that Eclipse Che uses Eclipse Orion as its code editor but, while multiple languages seem to be supported in Che, such information for Orion seem to be quite outdated and only JavaScript and other webdev seem to be supported. So:

Like Che, does Eclipse Orion also have editor plugins for

1. Java
2. Python
3. C/C++

and do those plugins have features like

```
 (a) Syntax highlighting 
 (b) Code completion 
 (c) Error detection and smart suggestions 
 (d) Rename refactoring...?
```

PS1: For my EC2, I could have used Che, but all I want is only its browser IDE without docker containers etc. Besides, running Che on EC2 apparently [requires](https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/1438) some ephemeral ports to be opened to the world because of docker etc.

PS2: Cloud9 would have worked but it doesnt have SSH access for free version.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Orion does not have language tooling for Java, Python or C/C++.  Only syntax highlighting is implemented for those languages.

Comment: When Che says it uses Orion for code editor, does that mean Che project has built editor plugins for those other languages on top of original Orion?